# Wagtail: Render child elements from different page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, wagtail

Normally when rendering child elements onto the page I use `{% for item in page.get_children %}`
and render them out like `{{ item.specific.name }}`

However, I want to now access the child elements from a page that is not within its own template. (eg rendering child elements from /about.html onto /home.html)

I imagine it's something like `{% for item in page.pagename.get_children %}` though I'm not sure of the actual page name...Do I have to define it somewhere/ is it defined somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd recommend doing your page fetching in a [`get_context` method](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html#overriding-context), so that you can use Django's ORM methods freely, rather than just the ones that can be written inside a template. In particular, you can use `Page.objects.get(...)` to retrieve a particular page based on title (or any other criteria):

```
class HomePage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['about_pages'] = Page.objects.get(title='About').get_children()
        return context
```

This will allow you to write `{% for item in about_pages %}` on your template.

If you can't rely on the page title to be a predictable title such as "About", then you'll have to decide what other criterion identifies it as "the About page". Common approaches would be to use the slug (`Page.objects.get(slug='about')`), which is a bit less likely to be changed by accident - or to define a dedicated `AboutPage` page type and fetch based on that: `AboutPage.objects.first()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add to the context of the page where you are doing the rendering a context variable for the page whose children you want to render:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['about_page'] = Page.objects.get(slug='about')
        return context
```

Then in `home.html` you would do:

```
{% for item in about_page.get_children.live.in_menu %}
```

(Use `.live` and `.in_menu` if you only want pages that meet these criteria.)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I'll leave this here incase anyone else stumbles upon this thread.

on page/model.py

```
casestudy_root = models.ForeignKey( # Page Navigation
    'wagtailcore.Page',
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    related_name='+',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
)

 content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        PageChooserPanel('casestudy_root', 'content.CaseStudyIndexPage'),
    ]
```

For html

```
{% for casestudy in page.casestudy_root.get_children %}
```

After the changes, run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate`

Don't forget to select the page in the admin panel